# How to get the bluetooth to detect and pair with devices like an android phone on Hp Stream 11?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth

I have recently received the Hp Stream 11 and thought that windows 8 was an overkill for a device of it's specs. I backed up windows and boot Xubuntu 14.04 from a live CD with memory persistence and everything appeared to work out of the box except the wifi, bluetooth, and the mounting of the local windows installation.

I then got a usb to ethernet adapter and was able to get the necessary wireless driver as proprietary hardware via software & updates application. After which I proceed to update and upgrade my system via the terminal which fixed the mounting of local drives issue (though I am not sure if the fix was permanent as after a restart they where faded out temporarily and unable to mount). So far I cannot seem to find a fix for the bluetooth though.

Blueman indicates that the bluetooth is on, and I have made both the android phone and the stream 11 discoverable, but to no avail. The stream nor the phone seem to detect each other. When i test to see if bluetooth works in Windows 8, the detection and pairing is almost instantaneous.

I have been searching the net for a while now with no apparent solution to this issue. Have any of the Ubuntu gurus found a work around for this yet?

Here is the machine for those not familiar: http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/Laptops/hp-stream-notebook---11-d010nr-energy-star?jumpid=ba_r329_hhocse&aoid=44661&003=6663635&010=K2L95UA%23ABA&ci_sku=K2L95UA%23ABA&ci_gpa=pla&ci_kw=#!&TabName=specs

I should probably also state that I have tried gnome bluetooth manager as well. Same issue so I'm assuming this is a driver problem.

Thanks in advance to all those who respond.

Addendum:

Terminal Input:
`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Output:

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl`

Terminal Input:
`lsusb`

Output:

`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0177 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b45e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The question has been edited.

Comment: You need to install firmware for you Broadcom bluetooth adapter.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link provided exactly, copying over the hcd file after conversion to /lib/firmware/brcm and then shutdown the computer and turned it on again. The only change I have noticed are that the bluetooth is off by default instead of being on when i start up as usual (not a big issue I just turn it on again from the bluetooth applet in the panel). However, blueman assistant gives the following error "No Adapters Found!".

Comment: Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/216c/' RS=` to your question and also `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: After shutting down my machine twice and restarting two times afterwards the bluetooth appears to be working. This includes transferring and receiving files. I am not sure what exactly changed (if you have any idea I am interested in knowing why numerous restarts and shutdowns might have helped), but it works. Thank you for your time and patience Pilot6. Also apologies for what seems to be a duplicated question. I willing be posting your link elsewhere to assist others.

Comment: Firmware has loaded finally. And also sometimes it is hard to turn on BT for the first time due to a bug somewhere in userspace, I guess.